# javascript - How can I get a div that is inside of a div?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="message cid-524f7e6b28946"><i class="icon icon-chat-manager"></i>
<div class="timestamp" style="display: block;">4:44pm</div><span class="from staff clickable">SamueI </span><span class="text">&nbsp;.</span>
```

I want to get the div "timestamp"

I want to change the timestamp text like this, but it comes up with "null"

```
 document.getElementById("timestamp").textContent = "new text";
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the [**querySelector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) like:

```
document.querySelector('.timestamp').textContent = "new text";
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7gMam/)

Or otherwise you need to use ID instead of Class in your element, like:

```
<div id="timestamp" style="display: block;">4:44pm</div>
```

Comment: In all my years, I have never seen the SelectorAPI.  Thanks for the intro!

Comment: @JaimeTorres, added the link to MDN :)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to be

```
<div class="message cid-524f7e6b28946"><i class="icon icon-chat-manager"></i>
<div id="timestamp" style="display: block;">4:44pm</div><span class="from staff clickable">SamueI </span><span class="text">&nbsp;.</span>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("timestamp").textContent = "new text";
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using getElementById even though timestamp is a class name. Change it to `id="timestamp"`

Answer (score 0):

Since IE9 there is also a getElementsByClassName, so it's quite safe to do something like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('timestamp')[0].textContent = "new text";
```